# Error morris.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando crear un grafico con morris.js, pero me da un error: 
`Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found
    at d [as constructor] (morris.min.js:6)
    at d.c [as constructor] (morris.min.js:6)
    at new d (morris.min.js:6)
    at Object.d [as Area] (morris.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (morris-data.js:6)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:2)`

He mirado soluciones, y una de ellas es poner los script al final, depues del div, pero no me soluciona nada. El div en cuestion, donde quiero que aparezca el grafico es el siguiente:

```
<%@page import="Clases.Usuario"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/logo_ur.png" />

    <title>UR Apuestas - Perfil</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="CSS/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="CSS/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/estilos.css">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="CSS/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top nav-sports" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header logo-sports">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="sports.jsp"><img src="img/logo_ur.png" class="logo-sports"/></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav user-sports">
                <li class="dropdown user-sports">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle usuario-sports" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="img/coins.png">  <%=(String) session.getAttribute("puntos")%> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="perfil.jsp"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-refresh"></i> Canjear</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-fw fa-refresh"></i> Recargar</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="ajustes.jsp"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i> Comprar</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown user-sports">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle mensajes-sports" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu message-dropdown">
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle usuario-sports" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-footer">
                            <a href="#">Read All New Messages</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown user-sports">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle usuario-sports" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>  <%=(String) session.getAttribute("user")%> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="perfil.jsp"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Perfil</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="ajustes.jsp"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Ajustes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <form action="ControladorUsuario" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name=""
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Salir</a>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li  class="dropdown user-sports">
                    <form action="ControladorUsuario" method="POST">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Salir</a>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav nav-right">
                    <div class="right-user-sports">
                        <center>
                            <h3> <%=(String) session.getAttribute("nombre")%> <%=(String) session.getAttribute("apellidos")%></h3>
                            <a href="perfil.jsp"><img src="img/profile.png" class="img-profile"></a>
                            <div class="progress level">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped " role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%=(String) session.getAttribute("exp")%>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em;width: <%=(String) session.getAttribute("exp")%>%">
                                    <%=(String) session.getAttribute("exp")%>%
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-double-down"></i> Deportes <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="futbol.jsp">Futbol</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="baloncesto.jsp">Baloncesto</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="tenis.jsp">Tenis</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="apuestas.jsp"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Mis Apuestas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="premios.jsp"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Premios</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="ranking.jsp"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i> Ranking</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contacto.jsp"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i> Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid body-sports">
                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/profile.png" class="img-profile">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <center>
                                    <h3>Imanol Urrutia Diaz</h3>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Cambiar imagen</a></p>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="well">Imanol Urrutia Diaz</div>
                        <div class="well">urrutia</div>
                        <div class="well">urrus88@gmail.com</div>
                        <div class="well">605025198</div>
                        <div class="well">Castro urdiales</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="info-box blue-bg">
                            <img src="img/coins-icon-perfil-bg.png" />
                            <div class="count"><%=(String) session.getAttribute("puntos")%></div>
                            <div class="title">URCoins</div>                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right fa-fw"></i> Donut Chart</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="morris-donut-chart"></div>
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <a href="#">View Details <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-futbol-o fa-fw"></i> Social</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row deportes-sports">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <img src="img/modificar-icon.png" class="sports-icon"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                    <div class="huge">Cambiar Datos</div>
                                                    <div>Cambia los datos de tu cuenta!</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="cambiarDatos.jsp">
                                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                                <span class="pull-left">Modernizate tio!</span>
                                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="panel panel-green">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <img src="img/apuestas-icon.png" class="sports-icon"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                    <div class="huge">Mis apuestas</div>
                                                    <div>Consulta tus apuestas!</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                                <span class="pull-left">Habras ganado? o perdido?</span>
                                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <img src="img/contacto-icon.png" class="sports-icon"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                    <div class="huge">Mensajes</div>
                                                    <div>Consulta los ultimos mensajes!</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                                <span class="pull-left">Rapido ti@!Que no tenemos todo el dia!</span>
                                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-futbol-o fa-fw"></i> Tu perfil</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row deportes-sports">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <img src="img/perfil-icon.png" class="sports-icon"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                    <div class="huge">Mi Perfil</div>
                                                    <div>Cambia los datos de tu perfil!</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                                <span class="pull-left">Actualizate!</span>
                                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="panel panel-green">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <img src="img/ajustes-icon.png" class="sports-icon"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                    <div class="huge">Ajustes</div>
                                                    <div>Configura los ajustes de la web!</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                                <span class="pull-left">Configurate!</span>
                                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <img src="img/contacto-icon.png" class="sports-icon"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                                    <div class="huge">Contacto</div>
                                                    <div>Contacta con nosotros!</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                                <span class="pull-left">Vamos!Que nos aburrimos...!</span>
                                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="JS/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="JS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="JS/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/morris-data.js"></script>

</body>

</html>


>
    <script src="JS/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/morris-data.js"></script>




function Donut(options) {
  this.resizeHandler = __bind(this.resizeHandler, this);
  this.select = __bind(this.select, this);
  this.click = __bind(this.click, this);
  var _this = this;
  if (!(this instanceof Morris.Donut)) {
    return new Morris.Donut(options);
  }
  this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
  if (typeof options.element === 'string') {
    this.el = $(document.getElementById(options.element));
  } else {
    this.el = $(options.element);
  }
  if (this.el === null || this.el.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("Graph placeholder not found.");
  }
  if (options.data === void 0 || options.data.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  this.raphael = new Raphael(this.el[0]);
  if (this.options.resize) {
    $(window).bind('resize', function(evt) {
      if (_this.timeoutId != null) {
        window.clearTimeout(_this.timeoutId);
      }
      return _this.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(_this.resizeHandler, 100);
    });
  }
  this.setData(options.data);
}

Donut.prototype.redraw = function() {
  var C, cx, cy, i, idx, last, max_value, min, next, seg, total, value, w, _i, _j, _k, _len, _len1, _len2, _ref, _ref1, _ref2, _results;
  this.raphael.clear();
  cx = this.el.width() / 2;
  cy = this.el.height() / 2;
  w = (Math.min(cx, cy) - 10) / 3;
  total = 0;
  _ref = this.values;
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    value = _ref[_i];
    total += value;
  }
  min = 5 / (2 * w);
  C = 1.9999 * Math.PI - min * this.data.length;
  last = 0;
  idx = 0;
  this.segments = [];
  _ref1 = this.values;
  for (i = _j = 0, _len1 = _ref1.length; _j < _len1; i = ++_j) {
    value = _ref1[i];
    next = last + min + C * (value / total);
    seg = new Morris.DonutSegment(cx, cy, w * 2, w, last, next, this.data[i].color || this.options.colors[idx % this.options.colors.length], this.options.backgroundColor, idx, this.raphael);
    seg.render();
    this.segments.push(seg);
    seg.on('hover', this.select);
    seg.on('click', this.click);
    last = next;
    idx += 1;
  }
  this.text1 = this.drawEmptyDonutLabel(cx, cy - 10, this.options.labelColor, 15, 800);
  this.text2 = this.drawEmptyDonutLabel(cx, cy + 10, this.options.labelColor, 14);
  max_value = Math.max.apply(Math, this.values);
  idx = 0;
  _ref2 = this.values;
  _results = [];
  for (_k = 0, _len2 = _ref2.length; _k < _len2; _k++) {
    value = _ref2[_k];
    if (value === max_value) {
      this.select(idx);
      break;
    }
    _results.push(idx += 1);
  }
  return _results;
};

Donut.prototype.setData = function(data) {
  var row;
  this.data = data;
  this.values = (function() {
    var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
    _ref = this.data;
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      row = _ref[_i];
      _results.push(parseFloat(row.value));
    }
    return _results;
  }).call(this);
  return this.redraw();
};

Donut.prototype.click = function(idx) {
  return this.fire('click', idx, this.data[idx]);
};

Donut.prototype.select = function(idx) {
  var row, s, segment, _i, _len, _ref;
  _ref = this.segments;
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    s = _ref[_i];
    s.deselect();
  }
  segment = this.segments[idx];
  segment.select();
  row = this.data[idx];
  return this.setLabels(row.label, this.options.formatter(row.value, row));
};
```

Comment: Podrías compartirnos el orden en el que importas los archivos javascript y en que sección del html se encuentran? tanto los de morris como sus dependencias y tu script de los datos

Comment: ahi lo tienes, gracias por responder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería indispensable que nos facilitaras el HTML completo y, sobre todo, si en la consola de depuración de red aparecen recursos que no han podido ser cargados (archivo no encontrado o similares) ya que he intentado reproducir tu problema y me ha funcionado correctamente.

He usado el mismo orden de carga de javascripts que tú, pero no me queda claro si intentas hacer uso de jQuery (la función `$( ... )`) antes de haberla cargado en el HTML. Si es así sube todas las etiquetas `<script>` por encima o bien usa `window.onload` para que se ejecute el código cuando todos los recursos (incluidos javascripts) hayan sido cargados.

**Moviendo `<script>`s antes del código**

```html
<!-- hojas de estilo -->
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css"/>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right fa-fw"></i> Donut Chart</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="morris-donut-chart"></div>
    <div class="text-right">
      <a href="#">View Details <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- carga de javascripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  Morris.Donut({
    element: 'morris-donut-chart',
    data: [{
      label: "Download Sales",
      value: 12
    }, {
      label: "In-Store Sales",
      value: 30
    }, {
      label: "Mail-Order Sales",
      value: 20
    }],
    resize: true
  });
});
</script>
```

**Usando `window.onload`**

```html
<!-- hojas de estilo -->
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css"/>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  Morris.Donut({
    element: 'morris-donut-chart',
    data: [{
      label: "Download Sales",
      value: 12
    }, {
      label: "In-Store Sales",
      value: 30
    }, {
      label: "Mail-Order Sales",
      value: 20
    }],
    resize: true
  });
};
</script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right fa-fw"></i> Donut Chart</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="morris-donut-chart"></div>
    <div class="text-right">
      <a href="#">View Details <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- carga de javascripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
```

Fíjate que pongas donde pongas tu código sólo se ejecutará cuando todos los recursos definidos en la página hayan sido cargados.

Comment: Ya esta editada la pregunta con el codigo completo. el html, el js que hace el grafico...  No me dejaba poner mas codigo, pero basicamente eso es lo importante

Comment: Algo debes tener mal en el HTML que has puesto porque no me valida como correcto. ¿Has ojeado mi respuesta? ¿Arroja algo de luz a tu problema? Voy a mirar tu código a ver qué le pasa.

Comment: Deberías preparar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) porque el que tienes no nos ayuda a reproducir tu problema. Creo que el anterior era más útil. Aún así revisa lo que has publicado porque hay un mayor-que suelto (`>`) y código javascript sin meter dentro de las etiquetas `<script>`. Por esos motivos no puedo usar tu última edición para reproducir tu problema :(

Comment: Si no puedes preparar el MCVE compárteme el código HTML generado por tu página (carga la página y pulsa Control+U para ver su código fuente). Así podré reproducir con más precisión tu entorno y encontrar el problema. Por cierto, ¿miraste lo que te puse en mi respuesta?

Comment: Ya lo solucione, el tema era que habia un script por encima que hacia conflicto... ya esta solucionado, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, un placer :)